# How to add hyperlink into Django easy_pdf

Tags: django, pdf

I can't find solution for inserting hyperlink into generated pdf from Django [easy_pdf](https://django-easy-pdf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0-dev1/). Link is displayed on pdf but as text. How to make this link clickable?

part of template.html:

```
<a href="{{campaign_url}}">{{item.campaign_name}}</a>
```

part of view.py:

```
from easy_pdf.rendering import render_to_pdf_response
return render_to_pdf_response(request, template_name, context)
```

campaign_url is in context dictictionary

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you. 
The url will depend on how you stored it in the database. If it is something like `https://www.something.com` you can use

`<a href="https://www.something.com/{{query_param}}"></a>`

if you decide to use django urls then something like

`<a href="{% url 'app:campaign_url_name' query_param %}"></a>`

You might want to look at the django documentation for more clarity. [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)